# How to bind ASP.NET Treeview control to a datatable?

Tags: .net, asp.net, javascript, html

I have this table structure:
- CategoryID 
- CategoryName 
- ParentID

I want to load data from this table into a treeview control, to be able to edit/delete these records.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more details see:  [How do you databind to a TreeView control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372820/how-do-you-databind-to-a-system-windows-forms-treeview-control) (the question is WinForms, but still applies to ASP.NET)

The long and short is that you can't databind to a TreeView.  TreeViews are hierarchical data structures and as such do not have a native binding mechanism.  You'll have to roll your own binding to do this.