# How to Use GridView to display XML Web Response By Attribute Name Instead of DataSet Column Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, gridview

I'm trying to display an XML Web Response using the ASP.Net form GridView. I'm new to the .NET framework so I'm struggling with some of the particulars.

I'm developing a search engine so the XML response is the result of a search for a particular phrase or word. This is a sample of the XML response

```html
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">8</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="qf">recordkey</str>
<str name="df">text</str>
<str name="echoParams">all</str>
<str name="indent">true</str>
<str name="wt">xml</str>
<str name="q">*:*</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="281" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="Date Created">2014-10-30</str>
<str name="Facility">*****</str>
<str name="Author">*********</str>
<str name="Source System ID">*******</str>
<str name="Data Source">************</str>
<str name="Title">ENGINEERING INITIATION</str>
<long name="_version_">1504985395557826560</long>
</doc>
<doc>
<str name="Date Created">2011-09-30</str>
<str name="Facility">*********</str>
<str name="Author">************</str>
<str name="Source System ID">***</str>
<str name="Data Source">***************</str>
<str name="Title">USE OF REGISTERED....</str>
<long name="_version_">1504985395859816448</long>
</doc>
<doc>.....
  ...........
```

I blocked out some of the content but you get the idea.

Once I get the response I use a StreamReader to read the xml and put it into a XMLDocument.

```html
  XmlDocument myXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();

            GridView1.DataSource = myXMLDocument; 

            StreamReader myXMLReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            ds.ReadXml(myXMLReader);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["str"];

            GridView1.DataBind();
```

After that I load it into a DataSet and bind the table "str" to the Gridview which produces this result

```html
name               str_Text               lst_Id doc_Id
qf                     recordkey                1      
df                      text                    1  
echoParams               all                    1  
indent                  true                    1  
wt                      xml                     1      
q                       *fire*                  1  
Date Created          2014-10-30                          0
Facility                *****                             0
Author                  ****                              0
Source System ID        ***                               0
Data Source             ****                              0
Title                    ****                             0
Date Created         2011-09-30                           1
Facility                ****                              1
Author                  ****                              1
Source System ID        ****                              1
Data Source             *****                             1
Title               USE OF REGISTERED...                  1
Date Created        2011-11-03                            2
Facility                ****                              2
Author                 *****                              2
Source System ID        ***                               2
Data Source           *******                             2
Title                REQUEST...                           2
```

Now, the problem, I'm having problems organizing the content in the gridview. It only recognizes the column names as field names. I want to be able to to organize the information into a more typical search format such as

Date Created - "Followed by the title here"

Author Name

But I can't manipulate those things because they aren't seen as fields. So my overarching question. How do I use the gridview so I can manipulate based on attributes instead of the column names in the dataset? Do I have to bind it to the grid differently? Is there a sort that needs to be coded (Like by doc ID)? I don't really care the method I just need to be able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following linq to extract data from the dataset

```
            var results = ds.Tables["str"].AsEnumerable()
                .Where(x => x.Field<string>("name") == "qf")
                .Select(y => y.Field<string>("str_Text"));​
```

I don't think the code above will be the best solution.  I think parsing line by line like a text document will give better results.  Try using a treeview like the code below :
[Recursive adding XML into TreeView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28884844/recursive-adding-xml-into-treeview)