# DisplayMember for TreeView Tag

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

All,

I am trying to set the Text of a Node equal to that of a given property that is contained in the Tag of the Node.

The idea is that I won't need update the Node.Text time and time again.
Something similar like ComboBox.DisplayMember in which you can specify the string name of the property.

Could something like this be easily setup? Or would it take quite an amount of time with overriding the OnPaint and such?

Any tips or pointers are welcome.

PS. The project is strictly WinForms.

Comment: Sounds like you are searching for [databinding TreeView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/372820/1997232).

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you for comment. Much obliged.